# Video upload and display in PHP?

Tags: php, video, video-streaming

I want to upload video to server and then display it on web page using some player (like youtube) using PHP.

My client ask: "Videos must be no longer than 2 minutes and in either Quicktime, WMV, Mp4 or FLV format."

Is there any opensource script which help me to upload a video with client requirements and then an opensource player which plays that video?

Please help!

Thanks

Comment: PHP is HTML preprocessor, not video editor.

Comment: I know that.. but there must be some plugin or something which can help in achieving it in PHP?

Comment: No. In PHP you can only handle the file upload. The rest is completely different realm. Playback, for example, is Flash (or other player). PHP do not playback videos. PHP runs on the server side. There is nobody to watch a video on the server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is my favourite solution:
http://flowplayer.org/

It enables to control the video quite a lot: it uses javascript settings and embedded flash video player.

Edit: if you look for good uploader, try
http://code.google.com/p/swfupload/

It can do multiple uploads, and filetype checks.

Answer (score 0):

You must, first of all, create links to the videos you want to play (I created mine on a separate page[index.html]). Then upon the click of a link, it will open the page (play.php). I assumed that index.html was displaying the links to the videos from the database, then the rest of the scripting for playing is handled by play.php. 
see codes below:

index.html

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<style type="text/css">
tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #f2f2f2
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<center>
<table width="53%" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td width="8%">S/NO</td>
    <td width="92%">NAME OF VIDEO FILE</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center">1</td>
    <td><a href="play.php?url=Funny_Naija_Video_Animation.mp4&pic=ng.png">Funny Nigeria Video Animation</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center">2</td>
    <td><a href="play.php?url=WildGeese.mp4&pic=wg.png">Joan Armatrading- 
  Flight of the Wild Geese - MP4</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

play.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <title>Fluid Width Video</title>

  <style>
    * { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
    body { 
      font: 16px/1.4 Georgia, Serif;
      width: 50%; 
      margin: 80px auto; 
      background: url(images/bglines.png);
    }
    h1 { font-weight: normal; font-size: 42px; }
    h1, p, pre, video, h2, figure, h3, ol { margin: 0 0 15px 0; }
    h2 { margin-top: 80px; }
    h1 { margin-bottom: 40px; }
    li { margin: 0 0 5px 20px; }
    article { background: white; padding: 10%; }
    pre { display: block; padding: 10px; background: #eee; overflow-x: auto; font: 12px Monaco, MonoSpace; }

    img { max-width: 100%; }

    .videoWrapper {
        position: relative;
        padding-bottom: 56.25%;
        padding-top: 25px;
        height: 0;
    }
    .videoWrapper iframe,
    .videoWrapper object,
    .videoWrapper embed {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    video {
      width: 100%    !important;
      height: auto   !important;
    }
    figure { display: block; background: #eee; padding: 10px; }
    figcaption { display: block; text-align: center; margin: 10px 0; font-style: italic; font-size: 14px; orphans: 2; }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
<?
if(isset($_GET['url'])){
$vid = "movies/".$_GET['url'];  
$pos = "movies/".$_GET['pic'];
if($pos == "movies/ng.png"){
    $cap = "Animation - Funny Play Station 3 Nigerin video clip";
}
if($pos == "movies/wg.png"){
    $cap = "Jordan Armsterdam - The flight of the Wild Geese";
}
?>
<figure>
    <video src="<?php echo $vid;?>" controls poster="<?php echo $pos;?>"></video>
    <figcaption><?php echo $cap; ?></figcaption>
</figure>

<?php }else{ echo "You must be a paid Student in order to watch video tutorial!"; }?>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var $allVideos = $(".js-resize"),
        $fluidEl = $("figure");

    $allVideos.each(function() {

      $(this)
        // jQuery .data does not work on object/embed elements
        .attr('data-aspectRatio', this.height / this.width)
        .removeAttr('height')
        .removeAttr('width');

    });

    $(window).resize(function() {

      var newWidth = $fluidEl.width();
      $allVideos.each(function() {

        var $el = $(this);
        $el
            .width(newWidth)
            .height(newWidth * $el.attr('data-aspectRatio'));

      });

    }).resize();
</script>

</body>

</html>
```