# how to display video in a php page

Tags: html5-video

```
<body>
  <video width="320" height="240" controls autoplay>
    <object data="movie.mp4" width="320" height="240">
        <embed width="320" height="240" src="Priyanka Chopra - Exotic ft. Pitbull - YouTube.MP4">
    </object>
  </video>
</body>
```

I am trying to display a video in my php web page but it is not playing it....the video is present on folder but not displaying it...above is the code that i tried.....can anyone help me ??

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp

Comment: @cristi_b http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: check this link : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023346/video-upload-and-display-in-php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Video:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls autoplay>
  <source src="Priyanka Chopra - Exotic ft. Pitbull - YouTube.MP4" type="video/mp4">
  Sorry, your browser doesn't support the video element.
</video>
```

Audio:

```
<audio controls>
  <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Sorry, your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Comment: if instead of a video i give a src for an audio will this code gonna work for the audio as well ??

Comment: You would need to change the tag, the file name, and the type. I've updated the answer with an example.

Comment: Sorry, your browser does not support the audio element.  what this line means

Comment: when the page is getting loaded it starts the video...but i dont want that...i want it to play when someone clicks on the play button

Comment: That message is displayed to users who have older browsers that do not support the video or audio tags. If you see the video, you won't see the error.  To stop it from auto playing, remove the word 'autoplay' from the tag as Magesh says.