# optimized streaming video html without javascript

Tags: html, video-streaming

I've found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22879404/8002602) to display video streaming,
the answer looks work with :

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls autoplay>
  <source src="Priyanka Chopra - Exotic ft. Pitbull - YouTube.MP4" type="video/mp4">
  Sorry, your browser doesn't support the video element.
</video>
```

but, why my video doesn't play well? if it's about speed connection, I can play 1080p video on youtube without buffer

any suggest please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is perfect, and it does not require internet speed as it is locally hosted. But it might require good hardware configuration of your system to run this flawlessly. Check your RAM usage and it required flush your browsers cache. These points might help.